# 32 bit version of mfc100u.dll?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a 32 bit app developed with VS2010, but the dependency walker says it depends on a 64-bit file named mfc100u.dll.

The problem here is some computers fail to start the app.

I have not been able to locate clear information about this.  Is there both 32 and 64 bit versions of this file?  If so, how do I ensure that the 32bit apps use one version and the 64bit apps use another?  (And if these apps are in the same directory?)

If the 32 bit has a different name, what is it?

Comment: Don't take much stock in what Depends tells you, it hasn't kept up with the times.  The 32-bit version of mfc100u.dll is located in c:\windows\syswow64, the directory that contains 32-bit executables.  The mapping from system32 to syswow64 is automatic.

Comment: I still need to understand the versions.  On my computer, System32 has a file that's 5394KB.  SysWow64 has 4267KB.  On another computer where the app doesn't work, in system32 the file is 5471KB.

Comment: Also, how can I see which file is a 64bit file?

Comment: You are asking the wrong questions.  It is your job to ensure that the proper runtime DLLs get deployed on the user's machine.  Either by creating an installer or by running the pre-made vcredist installer.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms235299.aspx

Comment: And I need to understand the 32/64 bit issues to update my installer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependency walker can often indicate 64-bitness of DLLs but is wrong. When running a 32-bit app WOW64 uses something called the File System Redirector:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384187(v=vs.85).aspx

All requests to System32 dir are redirected to the syswow64 folder (whether you want them to or not).

The app would not load if a 64-bit DLL was included, you'd get some sort of 'Bad image' error on start-up.

Try running a 32-bit version of Dependency Walker and see if that works properly for you.

**UPDATE:** The 32bit and 64bit versions of the MFC and C-runtimes have the same name. They are normally deployed using the redistributable MSI files and Windows will handle the linking at run-time. However, if you absolutely MUST have a specific version linked to your app you'll need to deploy them in the same folder as your app. Don't try and mix 32/64 bit versions in the same folder. Here's what Microsoft has to say on the subject:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235264.aspx

Note: Just to complicate the matter there are different redistributable versions of the same file, e.g. VS2010 SP1 versions.

Answer (score 0):

msvcr100.dll is either not designed to run on windows or it contains an eror . try installing  the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor support.